# How to implement "Done" for voice recognition and recording

Tags: android, android-intent

We are using android 4.0.4. When using the keyboard, it has a mic button. When we use the mic button, it has a "done" button displaying on the dialog box. You can see a done button as on the following video (though he does not press it):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ftGIv3w8R8

In reality, a person presses the done button to indicate he is finished talking. This is what we want to implement in an app we are working on. Our current work, based off

http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-how-to-implement-voice-recognition-a-nice-easy-tutorial/

does not have this function, the app just chooses a "silence" and it stops taking inputs. We want to be able to talk, and when we click "done", that is when it stops receiving input. What are we missing, where do we need to look please?
Thank you kindly for your help!

Comment: How to implement “Done” for voice recognition and recording at same time please give me some idea thanks

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is not stop taking inputs after one speak recognition cycle, you could hear for the click of done button and restart the voice recognition.

I could use more information probably a screen shot of the voice recognition part before I could help.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick reply! I tried but I cannot add a photo since I am new to the website. Please do check the youtube video, it has a done button on it.

Comment: So your app doesn't have the done button or done button isn't working, is that the issue ?